# listbox checkbox not binding to its source

Tags: c#, vb.net, mvvm, data-binding, listbox

I need help binding my checkbox list in listbox which is in a popup box. My XAML code is as follows

```
<Popup Name="popUser" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=BtnUserFilter}" StaysOpen="False" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,15">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                        <Button Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="BtnSelectAll" Click="BtnSelectAll_Click">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Select All" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>

                        <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Name="BtnUnselectAll" Click="BtnUnselectAll_Click">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Select None" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ListBox x:Name="lstUser" BorderThickness="0" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Userlists,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          Content="{Binding Path=UserIL, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

The code in viewmodel to which the listbox is bound to is

```
Dim test = (From c In Users Select New With {Key c.User}).Distinct
    Dim Cnt As Integer
    For Cnt = 0 To test.Count - 1
        UserLists.Add(New UserList(Of String) With {.IsChecked = True, .UserIL = test(Cnt).User})
    Next
```

The code populates all the users in the UserList Variable but doesn't show up in the ListBox. Am I not binding the checkbox properly? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that UserLists is an ObservableCollection because a regular list does not propagate changes made to its content to the UI.

Furthermore I would suspect you have a typo in your xaml by refering to the UserLists as Userlists (note case sensitivity)

> For purposes of resolving backing types, WPF XAML is case sensitive by
>   the same rules that the CLR is case sensitive. Object elements,
>   property elements, and attribute names must all be specified by using
>   the sensitive casing when compared by name to the underlying type in
>   the assembly, or to a member of a type.